# Use single observable for multiple rows in table

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js, observable

```
<div class="tbody" data-bind="foreach: displayItems">
    <div class="t-row">
        <div class="t-cell">
            <div class="manage-location-buttons">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" data-bind="toggleClick: $component.openEditPopup"></i> Edit
                </a>
                <div class="edit-table-popup" data-bind="visible: $component.openEditPopup">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a data-hash="#locationmanagement/managelocations/locationediting" data-bind="click: goToTab">Locations</a></li>
                        <li><a data-hash="#locationmanagement/managelocations/events" data-bind="click: goToTab">Events</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is my sample of custom table.

On Link click I will show `edit-table-popup` div like popup. Cause I use only one observable `openEditPopup` for all items, onclick I see popup for each row.

```
 openEditPopup = ko.observable<boolean>(false);
```

`toggleClick` - is custom dirrective, which changes boolean value to opposite

Is it possible to use only one observable but to show popup only for clicked row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

The `click` binding sends two arguments to an event handler:

1. The clicked `$data`,
2. The click-event.

If your click handler is an observable, this means it calls the observable like so: `yourObservable(data, event)`

Knowing that an observable is *set* by calling it with an argument, you can imagine what happens. Note that knockout ignores the second argument.

The solution would therefore be to change the `openEditPopup` from containing a `bool`, to containing a `displayItem`, and changing the `visible` binding to:

```
visible: $component.openEditPopup() === $data
```

An example:

```js
var vm = {

  selected: ko.observable("A"),
  items: ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
  
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p>Tabs</p>
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
  <span data-bind="text: $data, click: $parent.selected"></span>
</div>

<p>Content</p>
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
  <div data-bind="visible: $parent.selected() === $data">
    <h1 data-bind="text:$data"></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, all your rows are bound to one observable and so when you click the row it is setting it to true and all pop ups are showing up?

If so, this would suggest you have a popup per row? I'd recommend changing this and having one popup that is toggled per row and then set it's data to the selected row. Something like this can be achieved with the code below.

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  var rows = ko.observableArray([
      {id: 1, name: "gimble"}, {id: 2, name: "bob"}, {id: 3, name: "jess"}
    ]);
  
  var selectedRow = ko.observable();
  
  function showRowPopup(row)
  {
    //console.log(row.id);
        
    if(selectedRow() == row)
      selectedRow(null);
    else
      selectedRow(row);
  }
  
  return {
    rows: rows,
    showRowPopup: showRowPopup,
    selectedRow: selectedRow
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>


<div data-bind="foreach: rows">
  <div>
    <span data-bind="text: id"></span> - 
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.showRowPopup">Toggle Modal</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-bind="with: selectedRow">
  <h3>My Fake Modal</h3>
  <span data-bind="text: id"></span> - 
  <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to have for each row different popup, cause it can have some impact on performance as I am thinking